# I have a function read file but it can not read anything

Tags: c, file

```c
void readfile(Student SV[], int n, char fileName[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %f %s ", SV[i].ID, SV[i].name, 
            SV[i].gender, &SV[i].day, &SV[i].month, &SV[i].year, &SV[i].age, 
                SV[i].faculty, &SV[i].gpa, SV[i].aca_rating) == 10){
        printf("%s \n", SV[i].ID);
        printf("%s \n", SV[i].name);
        printf("%s \n", SV[i].gender);
        printf("%d/%d/%d \n", SV[i].day, SV[i].month, SV[i].year);
        printf("%d \n", SV[i].age);
        printf("%s \n", SV[i].faculty);
        printf("%f \n", SV[i].gpa);
        printf("%s \n", SV[i].aca_rating);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

and this is my file, how I can read my file

```
student information: 1
ID: SE1111
Name: Henry
Gender: Male
Day of birth: 14/01/1999
Age: 22
Faculty: SE
GPA: 8.00
Aca rating: Good student
__________________________________
student information: 2
ID: SE1234
Name: John
Gender: Male
Day of birth: 14/02/1999
Age: 22
Faculty: SE
GPA: 8.00
Aca rating: Good student
__________________________________
```

Comment: Until such time as a check for NULL against `fp` proves otherwise, I'm assuming that open *fails*. Second, is `student information: n` actually part of the *file* ? All those preambles need to be accounted for as well. This is asking for line-reading and tokenizing.

Comment: How do you expect `fscanf` to magically parse the part of each line that you want it to? Where in the code do you even attempt to skip the field name and store just the field value? Suggest you use `fgets` to read each line and then `strtok` with a delimiter token of `":"` to extract each field.

Comment: Also, the `while` loop is using the same `i` value every time. You should only have one loop with a condition that exits if `i` reaches `n` or if the file reading indicates there is no more data.

Answer (score 0):

fscanf() doesn't work the way that you are expecting it to work. So I implemented this function differently using fgets() instead. However, if it doesn't provide the exact outcome you are expecting, you can use it to get some ideas about how to traverse a file and capture data:

Function:

```
    void read_file(const char *filename, int n)
    {
        // n --> number of students you wanna show
        // filename --> name of the file
    
        /* Initialization */
        FILE *file;
        int counter;
        char data[500];
        char *occurance;
        Student student;
        char ID[100];
        char name[100];
        char gender[100];
        char faculty[100];
        char aca_rating[100];
        char age[50];
        char DOB[100];
        char gpa[100];
    
        file = fopen(filename, "r");
    
        if (file != NULL)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i != n)
            {
                fgets(data, sizeof(data), file);
                //remove newline
                data[strcspn(data, "\n")] = 0;
                //pointer to the string starting the semicolon
                occurance = strstr(data, ":");
                //if semicolon was found
                if (occurance != NULL)
                {
                    occurance++; //skip semicolon
                    occurance++; //skip whitespace
                    // now, occurance = student information number
                }
                //if semicolon wasn't found, that means it is a "____"
                else
                {
                    printf("\n");
                    // skip this line in the file: "____"
                    continue;
                }
    
                if (atol(occurance) == i + 1 && occurance != NULL)
                {
                    // traverse thru the lines after student information: n
                    for (counter = 0; counter < 8; counter++)
                    {
                        fgets(data, sizeof(data), file);
                        //remove newline
                        data[strcspn(data, "\n")] = 0;
                        //pointer to the string starting the semicolon
                        occurance = strstr(data, ":");
                        occurance++; //skip semicolon
                        occurance++; //skip whitespace
    
                        switch (counter)
                        {
                        case 0:
                            strcpy(ID, occurance);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            strcpy(name, occurance);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            strcpy(gender, occurance);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            strcpy(DOB, occurance);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            strcpy(age, occurance);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            strcpy(faculty, occurance);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            strcpy(gpa, occurance);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            strcpy(aca_rating, occurance);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                        }
                    }
    
                    student.ID = ID;
                    student.name = name;
                    student.gender = gender;
                    student.DOB = DOB;
                    student.faculty = faculty;
                    student.aca_rating = aca_rating;
                    student.age = atol(age);
                    student.gpa = atof(gpa);
                    printf("ID: %s \n", student.ID);
                    printf("name: %s \n", student.name);
                    printf("gender: %s \n", student.gender);
                    printf("DOB: %s \n", student.DOB);
                    printf("Age: %d \n", student.age);
                    printf("faculty: %s \n", student.faculty);
                    printf("gpa: %f \n", student.gpa);
      

              printf("aca rating: %s \n", student.aca_rating);
            }
            i++;
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student
{
    char *ID;
    char *name;
    char *gender;
    char *DOB;
    int age;
    char *faculty;
    float gpa;
    char *aca_rating;

} Student;

void read_file(const char *, int);

int main()
{
    read_file("stackoverflow.txt", 2);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't claim this is the best solution though but it works.

Comment: Hmm, I like the `fgets()`/`sscanf()` approach a lot, but you want to consider something other than `atoi()` for numeric conversion. `atoi()` provides *zero* error detection and will happily convert `"my cow"` to `0` silently without error in `int n = atoi ("my cow");`. Not really what you want.  What happens if there is only 1 student worth of data in the file?

Comment: You are right. I actually used atol not atoi in the code (the one with L). This one provide error detection.

Answer (score 0):

Sever initial points, while it is fine to pass `filename` to your function to open and read, you must validate that your file is actually open by ***checking the return** from `fopen()`. Additionally, it is generally better to open the file in the calling function and pass a `FILE*` pointer to the open stream. The validation of `fopen()` happens in the caller, and if the file cannot be opened, there was no need to make the function call to begin with.

While `fscanf()` will allow you to skip whitespace (including the `'\n'`), attempting to read a complex set of lines with a single `fscanf()` call is doomed to failure, and at best will provide a vary "fragile" read only if the input file format is perfect. Otherwise if the file has one bad student record, an extra or a missing line, your read breaks at that point for the entire remainder of the file.

Instead, when reading complex/multi-line data you are better off reading a line-at-a-time as @Zaki shows in his answer. There are several ways to approach it, the key is to read a line, keep track of which item in a student records is being read, and fully validate the conversion of whatever information is needed from the line. The labels in the input file provide a convenient way to have `sscanf()` help validate each record by matching the label. By having `sscanf()` match the label as part of extracting the needed information, it provide an exact way to ensure you are reading information from the correct line of input.

To create an input routine, you don't just code to handle the perfect input file format, you code to handle any input file format, extracting information from only the valid records present in the file.

**Example Input File**

For example, you should write your input routine so it gracefully handles an input file like the following.

```
$ cat dat/student_information.txt
student information: 1
ID: SE1111
Name: Henry
Gender: Male
Day of birth: 14/01/1999
Age: 22
Faculty: SE
GPA: 8.00
Aca rating: Good student
__________________________________
*********************************
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
!@$$@^^#$%&%*(*^$@%
(and other garbage making a bad student record)
__________________________________
student information: 2
ID: SE1234
Name: John
Gender: Male
Day of birth: 14/02/1999
Age: 22
Faculty: SE
GPA: 8.00
Aca rating: Good student
__________________________________
```

The input you show is present, but there is a bad record contained in the file. Your code should identify and discard the bad records, storing only the valid data.

You need a way to tell the calling function how many records were actually read from the file. Any time you are performing an operation in a function which could succeed or fail, you must provide a return that can indicate to the calling function the result of that operation. Making the return type `void` eliminates the primary way you have of indicating success/failure to the caller.

Here since you are reading student data, a good choice for return type is the number of student's data successfully read from the input file. Changing the return type to `size_t` allows you to return a `0` count if no data was read from the file, with a positive number indicating the number of students successfully read.

While reading the file, if invalid data is encountered, you have discovered a bad format within the file. Your function should then skip all data until the next line beginning with a `'_'` is found, and then should return to extracting data.

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```c
size_t readstudents (Student *SV, size_t max, FILE *fp)
{
    int item = 0,           /* record item 0-8 (information - aca_rating) */
        badfmt = 0;         /* bad format of student data flag, 1-skip to next '_' */
    size_t n = 0;           /* no. of students read */
    char buf[MAXREC];       /* buffer to hold each line of input */
    
    /* loop while n < max and line read */
    while (n < max && fgets (buf, MAXREC, fp)) {
        if (*buf == '_') {                  /* skip lines beginning '_' */
            item = badfmt = 0;              /* reset item count and badfmt flag */
            continue;
        }
        if (badfmt)                         /* if set, bad student, skip to next '_' */
            continue;
        
        switch (item) {     /* switch on item count */
        case 0: item += 1;  /* discard student information: X line, increment item */
                break;
        case 1: if (sscanf (buf, " ID: %s", SV[n].ID) != 1)     /* if failure on parse */
                    badfmt = 1;                                 /* set badfmt flag */
                item += 1; break;   /* item increment only relevant if good parse */
        case 2: if (sscanf (buf, " Name: %63[^\n]", SV[n].name) != 1)
                    badfmt = 1;
                item += 1; break;
        case 3: if (sscanf (buf, " Gender: %s", SV[n].gender) != 1)
                    badfmt = 1;
                item += 1; break;
        case 4: if (sscanf (buf, " Day of birth: %d/%d/%d",
                            &SV[n].day, &SV[n].month, &SV[n].year) != 3)
                    badfmt = 1;
                item += 1; break;
        case 5: if (sscanf (buf, " Age: %d", &SV[n].age) != 1)
                    badfmt = 1;
                item += 1; break;
        case 6: if (sscanf (buf, " Faculty: %s", SV[n].faculty) != 1)
                    badfmt = 1;
                item += 1; break;
        case 7: if (sscanf (buf, " GPA: %f", &SV[n].gpa) != 1)
                    badfmt = 1;
                else
                    item += 1;      /* condition increment before last on good parse */
                break;
        case 8: if (sscanf (buf, " Aca rating: %15[^\n]", SV[n].aca_rating) == 1)
                    n += 1;         /* increment student count after successful parse */
                break;
        default: fputs ("error: bad format\n", stderr);
            item = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return n;
}
```

Note above the `item` is used to keep track of which line within a student record is being read (`0 - 8`, e.g. `student information:` through `Aca rating:`) and `badfmt` is used as a flag and set to `1`/true if invalid input is encountered. The function then reads and discards lines until the next line beginning with `'_'` is found.

A complete program using the function above could be written as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/* adjust constants as needed */
enum { MAXFAC=4, MAXID=8, MAXACA=16, MAXNM=64, MAXSTUDENTS=100, MAXREC=512 };

#define MAXGENDER   MAXID

typedef struct {
    char ID[MAXID], name[MAXNM], gender[MAXGENDER], faculty[MAXFAC], aca_rating[MAXACA];
    int day, month, year, age;
    float gpa;
} Student;

size_t readstudents (Student *SV, size_t max, FILE *fp)
{
    int item = 0,           /* record item 0-8 (information - aca_rating) */
        badfmt = 0;         /* bad format of student data flag, 1-skip to next '_' */
    size_t n = 0;           /* no. of students read */
    char buf[MAXREC];       /* buffer to hold each line of input */
    
    /* loop while n < max and line read */
    while (n < max && fgets (buf, MAXREC, fp)) {
        if (*buf == '_') {                  /* skip lines beginning '_' */
            item = badfmt = 0;              /* reset item count and badfmt flag */
            continue;
        }
        if (badfmt)                         /* if set, bad student, skip to next '_' */
            continue;
        
        switch (item) {     /* switch on item count */
        case 0: item += 1;  /* discard student information: X line, increment item */
                break;
        case 1: if (sscanf (buf, " ID: %s", SV[n].ID) != 1)     /* if failure on parse */
                    badfmt = 1;                                 /* set badfmt flag */
                item += 1; break;   /* item increment only relevant if good parse */
        case 2: if (sscanf (buf, " Name: %63[^\n]", SV[n].name) != 1)
                    badfmt = 1;
                item += 1; break;
        case 3: if (sscanf (buf, " Gender: %s", SV[n].gender) != 1)
                    badfmt = 1;
                item += 1; break;
        case 4: if (sscanf (buf, " Day of birth: %d/%d/%d",
                            &SV[n].day, &SV[n].month, &SV[n].year) != 3)
                    badfmt = 1;
                item += 1; break;
        case 5: if (sscanf (buf, " Age: %d", &SV[n].age) != 1)
                    badfmt = 1;
                item += 1; break;
        case 6: if (sscanf (buf, " Faculty: %s", SV[n].faculty) != 1)
                    badfmt = 1;
                item += 1; break;
        case 7: if (sscanf (buf, " GPA: %f", &SV[n].gpa) != 1)
                    badfmt = 1;
                else
                    item += 1;      /* condition increment before last on good parse */
                break;
        case 8: if (sscanf (buf, " Aca rating: %15[^\n]", SV[n].aca_rating) == 1)
                    n += 1;         /* increment student count after successful parse */
                break;
        default: fputs ("error: bad format\n", stderr);
            item = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return n;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    size_t n;
    Student s[MAXSTUDENTS] = {{ .ID = "" }};
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    if ((n = readstudents (s, MAXSTUDENTS, fp)) == 0) {
        fputs ("error: no students read from file.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("\nStudent Info: %zu\n"
                "  ID:             %s\n"
                "  Name:           %s\n"
                "  Gender:         %s\n"
                "  Day of birth:   %02d/%02d/%d\n"
                "  Age:            %d\n"
                "  Faculty:        %s\n"
                "  GPA:            %.2f\n"
                "  Aca rating:     %s\n",
                i + 1, s[i].ID, s[i].name, s[i].gender, s[i].day, s[i].month, s[i].year,
                s[i].age, s[i].faculty, s[i].gpa, s[i].aca_rating);
                
}
```

The global `enum` is simply used to create six constants for the program. (you could have used a `#define` for each, but a global `enum` allows a convenient way to create multiple constants in a single line). Since `MAXGENDER` has the same value as `MAXID`, a separate `#define` was required.

Also note, you only need a single `printf()` to output any continual block of output.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/student_information dat/student_information.txt

Student Info: 1
  ID:             SE1111
  Name:           Henry
  Gender:         Male
  Day of birth:   14/01/1999
  Age:            22
  Faculty:        SE
  GPA:            8.00
  Aca rating:     Good student

Student Info: 2
  ID:             SE1234
  Name:           John
  Gender:         Male
  Day of birth:   14/02/1999
  Age:            22
  Faculty:        SE
  GPA:            8.00
  Aca rating:     Good student
```

There is a lot there, so slow down and work though it so you understand the purpose for each line and expression. Let me know if you have additional questions.